# Messages and soagent making CPU spike - any solutions?

Tags: macos, messages, cpu

I've had my MacBook for 3 years and have never had this issue... Recently (maybe a month ago?) Messages and soagent are making my CPU spike. It sounds like my MacBook is about to take off into outer space so I have to kill both processes in my Activity Monitor. That fixes my issue, temporarily, until I open Messages again and it starts all over. I've tried researching this but don't really seem to find a fix.

**I'm running Mac OS Sierra, v 10.12.6**

This is driving me insane... any suggestions?

Comment: `soagent` has to do with your address book.

Comment: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessagesKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/soagent.app/Contents/MacOS/soagent

Comment: so possibly something wrong with your Address Book.

Comment: Do you have your Contacts synced with any cloud services such as iCloud, Google, Outlook, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue after I updated my mid 2012 mac book to Mojave. SOAGENT & CALLEDSERVICES were taking up more than 100% CPU.

I exported all the contacts to the VCF file format and saved on desktop.
Deleted all the contacts from the contacts list
Restarted computer
Imported back the contacts

My issue was resolved. Hope this helps